# What is __NSFrozenArrayM in Core Data Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

i'm trying to fetching coredata entity but it gives this __NSFrozenArrayM and i don't get my array of entity. if any one have idea about then please tell me.
Thanks In advance

This is console :-

```
    <__NSFrozenArrayM 0x6000014468e0>(
    <ExpenseInfo: 0x60000270dea0> (entity: ExpenseInfo; id: 0x92d7006a96eb7229 <x-coredata://B5FE3C43-17E6-4BEA-B3F4-E8093CA29D37/ExpenseInfo/p185> ; data: <fault>),
)
```

This is my code :-

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

   NSError *error;

    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy] ;

    return mutableFetchResults;
```

Comment: Show your code that you are using to fetch your core-data entity.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Please check i added code

Comment: Please don't add arbitrary tags. There is no [swift] code in your question.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry next time i will take care of this thing. Thanks You Big Fan of yours :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**__NSFrozenArrayM**  an immutable NSArray sharing its storage with an NSMutableArray that it was -copy'd from (will do a real copy if the original array is mutated).

Reference: https://gist.github.com/Catfish-Man/bc4a9987d4d7219043afdf8ee536beb2

Comment: But if this return an __NSArrayM OR  __NSFrozenArrayM  then i'm not able to fetch data because of it return with Fault entity !! and i also try shouldfault method to false but it does not working

Comment: @YogeshPatel, This is not an issue with reference array, you need to set `[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO]` to prevent fault data.

Comment: Hello Mayur, i use this setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO and now it's working. I don't have 15 Reputation so don't able to upvote your answer. Thanks For Your Time :)

Comment: @YogeshPatel, Np, Once you have 15+ Reputation you can accept this answer. Thanks. Happy to Help you. :)

Comment: Yes Sure Thanks For Your help :)

Comment: @YogeshPatel, If possible than accept this answer, So it can be helpful to other people also, who will face this type of issue or they need to gain more knowledge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185601/discussion-between-mayur-karmur-and-yogesh-patel).